# How to use Link Type:External in FlexBuilder/FlashBuilder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

As title, I want to use swc library with External link type in flashbuilder, but it always report errors that class not found. Is anyone known how to use this link type?

Comment: Though i tried the same as you said, but me too get the same error. but my opinion is use the merge into code, since most swc are less sized one.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. But my project has more than one module(each module will be compiled to a swf), if all the modules use Merge Into Code, will increase swf size greatly.

Comment: oh, but be sure that whole project size should not be more than 2MB, If it is higher that even on dedicated servers too take very long time to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Are the errors at compile time, or runtime?

If at compile time, make sure that you are referencing the SWFs' directories.  (**Project | Properties | Actionscript Build Path | Source Path** *(and add the necessary entries)*)